# Forming the Eigenspace (doubts)

Tags: linear-algebra

I had a matrix which I solved for a characteristic poly = (1-λ)(2-λ)(2-λ). when I was solving for the eigenspace corresponding to **λ=1**, I got a 3x3 matrix in RREF of : \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
The solution manual states the solution "http://prntscr.com/jwh3x4"

My question is that why is my method of solving the eigenspace = **t[1,0,0] + s[0,1,0]** incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your solution to be right as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the eigenspace is the kernel of some matrix. What you gave is the span of that RREF, and not the kernel of the matrix.

You want to look at the solutions to the following system:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

You should note that solutions to this equation must have $y = z = 0$, but $x$ is free to be whatever it wants to be. Hence, the kernel of this matrix (and thus the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $1$) is given by

$$\left\{t\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$$

Comment: Makes sense I suppose. The thing is, we haven't studied about Kernal at all. Is there anyway else to see this? Thanks.

Comment: Strange that you guys are working with eigenstuff before learning what a kernel is. The kernel of a matrix $A$ is simply the solutions to $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$. In this case, the kernel of $A - I$ is your eigenspace.

Comment: If I had a 3x3 matrix [1,0,0;  0,1,0;  0,0,0], then the eigenspace which is the null space of A−I is just  t(0, 0, 1). Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.